# tar archive includes less files than the result of find command

Tags: linux, find, tar, xargs

I run the following command: 
**find . -type f -name "*.xml" -mtime +30 | wc -l**
- to know how many files older than X are there in current directory.

Now I want to tar them and when I create the archive using above command plus **| xargs tar -czvf archive_name.tar**
- everything seems ok, but..

Now I want to know how many files are in final archive so I run another command which is:
**tar -tvf archive_name.tar | wc -l** 
- I get about **2K**.

The problem is that first **find** returns about **6K** files.

How can that be? (there are no other directories in current dir).

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argument list of a process is not infinite-sized, so xargs have to launch tar several times to process them all. So it would be equivalent to run:

```
tar -czvf archive_name.tar 1.xml 2.xml ...
tar -czvf archive_name.tar a.xml b.xml ...
tar -czvf archive_name.tar za.xml zb.xml ...
```

and the last instance of tar will overwrite the file.

You may overcome it by appending to the archive (switch r) instead of creating:

```
find . -type f -name "*.xml" -mtime +30 | xargs tar rvf archive_name.tar
```

Note that it creates an uncompressed archive, you may compress it afterwards with gzip or whatever.

Comment: Hi Fat-Zer, so let's say that xargs run tar command 3 times, there still should be about 6K files in the archive or - is it about being able to tar only 2K out of these 6K?

Comment: @AbbyLockhart, actually not, the last execution of tar will just overwrite the archive. [added to the answer]